# How can I communicate with my services in my gitlab job?

Tags: docker, service, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following gitlab job:

```yaml
build-test-consumer-ui:
  stage: build
  services:
  - name: postgres:11.2
    alias: postgres
  - name: my-repo/special-hasura
    alias: graphql-engine
  image: node:13.8.0-alpine
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  script:
  - wget -q http://graphql-engine/v1/version
```

The docker image `my-repo/special-hasura` looks more or less like this:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v1.3.3.cli-migrations

ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:@postgres:/postgres"
ENV HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES="startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log"

COPY ./my-migrations /hasura-migrations

EXPOSE 8080
```

When I run my gitlab job, then I see that my hasura instance initializes properly, i.e. it can connect to postres without any problem (the connection url `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL` seems to be fine). However, I cannot access my hasura instance from my job's container, in the `script` section. The output of the command is

```
wget: bad address 'graphql-engine'
```

I suppose that the job's container is not located in the same network as the service containers. How can I communicate with the `graphql-engine` service from my job container? I am currently using gitlab-runner 13.2.4.

### EDIT

Looking at the amount of answers to this question, I guess there is no easy way. Therefore I'll switch to `docker-compose`. Instead of using the `services` that I can theoretically define in my job, I'll use `docker-compose` in my job and that'll achieve exactly the same purpose.

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Comment: Nope, I'm using docker-compose instead.